# How to easily play back to back .m4a files programmatically on an iOS iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, xcode4

How can I play more than one .m4a file consecutively?

Presently, my function starts playing one, using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound etc., uses AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion to select a callback, and then returns.  When the sound is done, the callback lets my software continue.

This is a LOT of coding whenever there is back to back sound.

Can my software start a .m4a playing, and SOMEHOW wait for it to complete, waiting waiting for its callback to set a flag?   Can I use pthread software to do a wait loop with a multitasking pause?

Here's my code so far...

// Restore game_state to continue game after playing sound file.
int game_state_after_sound;
void play_sound_file_done ( 
                           SystemSoundID  ssID, 
                           void           *calling_class 
                           ) 
{ 
    printf("\n  play_sound_file_done."); 
    // Sound is now done, so restore game_state and continue to manage_game from where left off:
    game_state = game_state_after_sound;
    [ (GeController*)calling_class   manage_game];
}

```
// Plays sound_file_m4a and returns after playing has completed.
-(void) play_sound_file: (NSString *) sound_file_m4a
{
    printf("\n play_sound_file '%s' ", [sound_file_m4a UTF8String] );
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_file_m4a ofType:@"m4a"]; 
    SystemSoundID soundID; 

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID); 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID); 
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion ( soundID, NULL, NULL, play_sound_file_done, (void*)self ); 

    game_state_after_sound = game_state;
    game_state =  DELAY_WHILE_PLAYING_SOUND;
}
```

**********************************  AVPlayer work-in-progress...

But this produces no sound.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFfoundation.h> 

-(void) play_queued_sounds: (NSString *) sound_file_m4a
{
    printf("\n queue_sound_file: '%s' ", [sound_file_m4a UTF8String] );

    AVPlayerItem *sound_file = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_file_m4a ofType:@"m4a"]]]; 
    AVQueuePlayer *player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sound_file, nil]];  

    [player play]; 

    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not get the AVQueuePlayer solution to work.

GREAT SOLUTION:
For each sound to play, spin up a thread that awaits then locks a mutex, then does AudioServicesPlaySystemSound.  Just spin up a thread for each successive sound to play, and use the pthread mutex to delay each successive thread until the AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion function unlocks the mutex.  Works like a champ.

This is 21st century embedded programming:  Throw threads at the problem!

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved quite easily in `AVQueuePlayer`. You don't have to handle completion or anything, you just give it the AVPlayerItems that you want to play in sequence and call play. Here's an example:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFfoundation.h>


//AVPlayerItem *item1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFileName" ofType:@"m4a"]]];
```

**EDIT:** Use this instead

```
AVPlayerItem *item1 = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"2"] ofType:@"mp3"]]];

AVQueuePlayer *player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, nil]];

[player play];
```

Just as an addition, this can also be achieved with items from the users iPod library using a `MPMusicPlayerController` queued from the `didPickMediaItems` delegate method of `MPMediaPickerController`

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [player setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: Questions:
How do I specify a .m4a file for it to play?
Does "[self.player play];" wait for all to finish playing?

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell I've edited my post showing how to retrieve a m4a from your apps bundle and play it. Using this code all you have to make `AVPlayerItems` for all the m4a's you want to use, add them to the queue player's array and then when you call `play` the queue player will start playing the first some, then continue playing through every song in the queue.

Comment: I get "Unknown type" for AVQueuePlayer even though I added the AVFoundation class to my xcode4 target.
duh.  I forgot the #import.  sorry.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell Did you import the framework into your controller? Adding `#import <AVFoundation/AVFfoundation.h>` to the top of your header file will silence this error.

Comment: Note:  I'm creating the .m4a sounds using iPhone voice memo.  These play okay using the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound method.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell That shouldn't be a problem, and sorry about this that was my fault, I posted incorrect string formatting for the file url. Please see the edit to my post.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell additionally, in order to ensure this doesn't crash take note that I have used "arrayWithObjects:" so you'll need to make sure there are at least two AVPlayerItems, and make sure you test this on a real device there is a known compatibility issue with AVQueuePlayer and the simulator.

Comment: Sorry for this post getting a little messy, folks.  I'm solving the problem at another post, but will come back and clean this one up with the solution when we get it working.